# Unknown error. Website Content Download program

Tags: android, android-asynctask, webcontent

i am trying to download content of website say "http://www.posh24.se/kandisar" and i have checked my program 100s of time but didnot find any solutions. please look into it. i am trying to put all content of website on my Log but i am only getting "Failed" Msg.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result="";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;

            try{

                url=new URL(urls[0]);

                Log.i("URL: ", urls[0]);

                urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                InputStream in=urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data=reader.read();

                while(data!=-1)
                {
                    char current=(char) data;
                    result+=current;
                    data=reader.read();

                }
                return result;

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed!";
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task=new DownloadTask();
        String result="";
        try {
            result=task.execute("http://www.posh24.se/kandisar").get();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
         Log.i("Content of Url: ", result);

    }

}
```

**and Logcat is**

```
06-30 07:40:02.582 23015-23015/? I/hecelebritygam: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-30 07:40:02.611 23015-23015/? W/hecelebritygam: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
06-30 07:40:02.884 23015-23015/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame W/hecelebritygam: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
06-30 07:40:02.889 23015-23015/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame I/chatty: uid=10101(com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame) identical 10 lines
06-30 07:40:02.890 23015-23015/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame W/hecelebritygam: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
06-30 07:40:02.933 23015-23015/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-30 07:40:03.688 23015-23026/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame I/hecelebritygam: Background concurrent copying GC freed 6131(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 54% free, 1305KB/2MB, paused 8.282ms total 280.862ms
06-30 07:40:03.753 23015-23015/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame W/hecelebritygam: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
06-30 07:40:03.754 23015-23015/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame W/hecelebritygam: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
06-30 07:40:04.002 23015-23041/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame I/URL:: http://gogarbhaipa.com/
06-30 07:40:04.054 23015-23041/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
06-30 07:40:04.073 23015-23041/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to gogarbhaipa.com not permitted
06-30 07:40:04.075 23015-23041/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:115)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:458)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:244)
        at com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:36)
06-30 07:40:04.077 23015-23041/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame W/System.err:     at com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
06-30 07:40:04.078 23015-23041/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
06-30 07:40:04.097 23015-23041/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
06-30 07:40:04.098 23015-23015/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame I/Content of Url:: Failed!
06-30 07:40:04.171 23015-23015/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
06-30 07:40:04.382 23015-23043/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
06-30 07:40:04.382 23015-23043/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-30 07:40:04.382 23015-23043/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
06-30 07:40:04.383 23015-23043/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
06-30 07:40:04.383 23015-23043/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
06-30 07:40:04.402 23015-23043/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe0205300: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
06-30 07:40:04.417 23015-23043/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0205300: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe0203780)
06-30 07:40:04.509 23015-23043/com.example.kiran.guessthecelebritygame D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0205300: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe0203780)
```

When i execute it, it show above logcat. i dont know what is wrong with it. why its keep failing.
hope i will get some simple answer. i am still a learner of android.

Comment: Try this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Answer (score 0):

Try to add different popular web address to confirm that there is no issue with the existing web address. I think it's the issue with the **SSL Certificate** of that website